# How to read pixel after pixel in bmp

Tags: c++, bitmap, rgb

I have a problem! I would like to get the RGB information of each pixel in 24-bit bitmap.
Till now i wrote a code which is getting an information about bitmap, but i have a problem with gettin RGB information about each pixel. I would like to keep this information in tabel pixs of structures Pixel. 
Could you help me with that?

I put my code below:

```
     #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma pack(2)

struct BITMAPFILEHEADER             // File header
{ 
  char bfType[2];                   // File type: should be BM ( 0x42 0x4D ) 
  int bfSize;                       // File size in bytes
  short bfReserved1;                // Reserved - for what i have no idea :P 
  short bfReserved2;                // -||-
  int bfOffBits;                    // Offset, adress of the beginning of the information about image (pixels )
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER             // Bitmap header
{
  unsigned int biSize;              // Size of this header
  unsigned int biWidth;             // Width of image ( in pixels)
  unsigned int biHeight;            // Height of this image ( in pixels )
  unsigned short biPlanes;          // Numer of color planes, always 1
  unsigned short biBitCount;        // Number of bytes for pixel. Possibility values :1,4,8,16, 24 and 32
  unsigned int biCompression;       // Used compression (0 -none)
  unsigned int biSizeImage;         // Size of image 
  signed int biXPelsPerMeter;       // Horizontal resolution of the image (pixel per meter)
  signed int biYPelsPerMeter;       // Vertical resolution of the image (pixel per meter)
  unsigned int biClrUsed;           // Number of colors in the color palette, or 0 to default to 2^n ( 0- no palette)
  unsigned int biClrImportant;      // Number of important colors used
};



#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct Pixel{
    unsigned int blue;  // or double?
    unsigned int green;
    unsigned int red;
    //unsigned char reserved;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(){

    // Openning the file

    cout << "Openning the file for reading: "<< endl;
    _getch();
    ifstream ifs("moj.bmp", ios::binary);

    if(!ifs){
        cout << " There is no such of file ";
        _getch();
        return 0;   
    } 

    // Reading information about BITMAPFILEHEADER
    char* temp = new char[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
    ifs.read(temp, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    BITMAPFILEHEADER* bfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)(temp);

    cout << "\n FILHEADER\n";
    cout << "\n File type: " << bfh->bfType[0] << bfh->bfType[1] << endl;
    cout << " File size: " << bfh->bfSize << endl;
    cout << " Offset(adress of beggining of the image information): " << bfh->bfOffBits << endl;
    _getch();


    // Reading information about BITMAPINFOHEADER
    temp = new char[sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];
    ifs.read(temp, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    BITMAPINFOHEADER* bih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(temp);

    cout << "\n INFOHEADER\n";
    cout << "\n Header size: " << bih->biSize << endl;
    cout << " Image width: " << bih->biWidth << endl;
    cout << " Image height: " << bih->biHeight << endl;
    cout << " Number of bytes for pixel: " << bih->biBitCount << endl;
    cout << " Used compression: " << bih->biCompression << endl;
    cout << " Image size: " << bih->biSizeImage<< endl;
    cout << " Horizontal resolution: " << bih->biXPelsPerMeter << endl;
    cout << " Vertical resolution: " << bih->biYPelsPerMeter << endl;
    cout << " Number of colors in the color palette: " << bih->biClrUsed << endl;
    cout << " Number of important colors used: " << bih->biClrImportant << endl;
    _getch();

    Pixel** pixs = new Pixel*[bih->biHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < bih->biHeight ; ++i)
        pixs[i] = new Pixel[bih->biWidth];


    ifs.seekg(bfh->bfOffBits, ios::beg); // bfOffBits points for beginning of the image information


               /* I have no idea how to read pixel after pixel in this moment */


    _getch();

    for (int i = 0; i < bih->biHeight; ++i) 
        delete pixs[i];

    delete pixs;
    delete bfh;
    delete bih;

    return 0;

}
```

---

This is working, but how should i change this on some integer variable? For example:

```
pixs[i][j]=(unsigned int)r;
```

is not working. Ater this command in pixs[i][j] are some trash... :/

Maybe some advice?

Comment: Why your pixel color is of type `int`? If you don't need more than 8bit per pixel, `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) should be enough.

Comment: Yes, i know this now, that there should be unsigned char. But i still have a big problem in one moment i mean in moment when i am reading the pixel, becos read function as first argument needs *char and i have no idea how to do this to make this things work... :/

Answer (score 0):

When you have *offset* and *image size* and you are sure the image is 24bit (1byte for each color), you ca scan your image buffer pixel after pixel.

```
uint8_t* pixelTmp = new uint8_t[3];
for (int i = 0; i != imageSize; ++i) {
    ifs.read(pixelTmp, 3);
    pixelTmp[0]; /* is blue 0-255 */
    pixelTmp[1]; /* is green 0-255 */
    pixelTmp[2]; /* is red 0-255 */
}
```

Assign value of `pixelTmp[0]` to your own pixel blue and so on...

Comment: But guys... did you check out how ifs.read() works. First argument of this sunction is char , thats why i have a big problem. So: int r, g, b; ifs.read(&b, 1); ifs.read(&g, 1); ifs.read(&r, 1); doesnt work, also uint8_t pixelTmp = new uint8_t[3]; for (int i = 0; i != imageSize; ++i) { ifs.read(pixelTmp, 3); pixelTmp[0]; /* is blue 0-255 / pixelTmp[1]; / is green 0-255 / pixelTmp[2]; / is red 0-255 */ }

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), 1 pixel uses 3 bytes. This means that the first byte is blue, the second green and the third is red. What you should do now, is loop through the rest of the bitmap file, reading 3 separate bytes, and storing them in your struct:

```
char r, g, b;
ifs.read(&b, 1);
ifs.read(&g, 1);
ifs.read(&r, 1);
```

You can check example 1 to see how the rows of the image are stored.

Comment: Joahim, thanks for correction, but i already know that biBitCount is the number of bits for pixels. It was a typo... :P
Anyway... wow... thanks guys for your help. Really. Now i will just test this, and tell you how it went :)

Comment: But guys... did you check out how ifs.read() works. First argument of this sunction is    *char  , thats why i have a big problem. So: int r, g, b; ifs.read(&b, 1); ifs.read(&g, 1); ifs.read(&r, 1); doesnt work, also uint8_t* pixelTmp = new uint8_t[3]; for (int i = 0; i != imageSize; ++i) { ifs.read(pixelTmp, 3); pixelTmp[0]; /* is blue 0-255 */ pixelTmp[1]; /* is green 0-255 */ pixelTmp[2]; /* is red 0-255 */ }

Comment: The first argument is char*, a pointer to a buffer. Since you read one chararcter, you can just pick the pointer to the variables. 

I was thinking of the fgetc function, that's why I picked ints instead of chars. I've fixed my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

First of, the `biBitCount` field of the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is **not** the number of *bytes* per pixel, it's the number of *bits*.

This is the number of bits you need to read from the raw data to get one pixel. For 24-bit pixels, just read as suggested in the answers from Alessandro Pezzato or Ben. 32-bit pixels contains an extra byte which normally contains an alpha channel (how transparent the pixel is.) There are multiple different 16-bit formats, and 8-bit format is usually an index into a colour table. I don't know about 4-bit formats, but 1-bit is pure black-and-white (0 is black and 1 is white.)

For the 8, 16, 24 and 32 bit formats, read one to four bytes and convert according to the colour format. For values less than 8 (4 and 1) read one byte at a time, and then use masking in a loop to get the bits, and store in your internal format.